# CSS div layouts in place of tables

Tags: html, css, alignment, css-tables

Is there a way to, without tables, get three or four elements to align with each other like this:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/fvPQw.png]

I ask this because currently I am using tables, but the tables are refusing to allow me to make the "test" box a specific height, and make filler be the one that actually fills in the space. Currently, it will only allow filler to have a specified height, and requires that the "test" box fill in all remaining space. If you can find a way for me to set the height of the bottom row of a table, then I will accept that as an answer too, but I figured the best way to do this would probably be with css layouts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can use a series of divs to mimic a table-like layout like in your screenshot.

For example, your HTML layout would be something like this:

```
<div class="header"><p>Top bar</p></div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="leftCol">
        <div id="topLeft">Top Left</div>
        <div id="centerLeft">Filler</div>
        <div id="bottomLeft">Test</div>
    </div>

    <div id="rightCol">
        <p>SPAM!</p>                
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

Then you'd apply styling like so:

```
.clear {
    clear: both;
}


#leftCol {
    float: left;
    width: 300px; /* explicit width on left column */
}

#topLeft {
    height: 100px; /* arbitrary height of top left spot; do not define for auto-sizing */
}

#centerLeft {
    height: 50px; /* another arbitrary height */
}

#bottomLeft {
    height: 200px; /* another arbitrary height */
}
```

​

I've made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5YdP7/) as an example. Basically you're floating your "left column" on the left and letting your content exist on the right.

Comment: Thank you so much! While I did not use your exact implementation, your examples DID provide me with MUCH BETTER understanding of floats, and introduced me to the float clear, which I had no idea even existed. These combined allowed me to complete my theme, which is quite relieving. +1 for the great example, also with jsfiddle which let me play around myself. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just be sure to set the left margin and width for each div to be the same and you can alter the top and bottom margins to make them fit how you'd like. This way, you can also change the height for any div you wish

Comment: What about the content off to the side? That's what I am really struggling with. I've tried float left, float right, spans, divs, everything, to no avail